# Partial Case-Insensitive String Search in R

Tags: r, string, matching, case-insensitive

I have a `spotify$gens` column where it contains all the descriptions of genres of each album.

For example:
`head(spotify$gens)` gives

```
gens = c("Jazz Fusion", "Latin Rock, Progressive Rock", "Progressive Rock", 
"Blues Rock, Electric Blues", "Electric Texas Blues, Electric Blues", "Piano Blues, Chicago Blues")
```

I want to use what I have made:

```
keyGenres = c("Pop","Rock","Hip Hop","Latin",
  "Dance","Electronic","R&B","Country","Folk",
  "Acoustic","Classical","Metal","Jazz","New Age",
  "Blues","World","Traditional")
```

to match the `spotify$gens` and return the matching part of the string string.

I have this code right now:

```
for (i in seq_along(spotify$gens)){
  for (genre in keyGenres){
    if( spotify$gens[i] %ilike% keyGenres[genre]){
       spotify$gens[i] <- keyGenres[genre]
    } else{
      spotify$gens[i] = spotify$gens[i]
    }}}
```

but it is returning me this error:
`Error in if (spotify$gens[i] %ilike% keyGenres[genre]) { :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

An example result i want would be
`spotify$gens[1] = "Jazz Fusion"` to `spotify$gens[1] = "Jazz"`

Some albums have more than one genre and I want to return the first string that is matched only.

Can anyone help me out? Thank you!!

Comment: Sounds like you have some missing values in your `gens` column. `if()` doesn't like missing values. Try `if( spotify$gens[i] %ilike% keyGenres[genre] & !is.na(spotify$gens[i]) )`

Comment: @GregorThomas Didn't seem to do it for me :( There doesn't seem to be any missing values in `gens`

Comment: Ah, simpler problem. You wrote your loop using `genre` as an integer, so you need the `seq_along` in `for (genre in seq_along(keyGenres))`.

Comment: `if` doesn’t like vectors of length greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your loop using is that you're using `genre` as an integer, so you need the `seq_along` in `for (genre in seq_along(keyGenres))`:

```
for (i in seq_along(gens)){
  for (genre in seq_along(keyGenres)){
    if( gens[i] %ilike% keyGenres[genre]){
       gens[i] <- keyGenres[genre]
    } else{
      gens[i] = gens[i]
    }}}
gens
# [1] "Jazz"  "Rock"  "Rock"  "Rock"  "Blues" "Blues"
```

We can use `str_replace_all` which is vectorized, and allows for a vector of regex patterns and replacements to eliminate the loops. This will be **much** more efficient:

```
library(stringr)
pat_replace = setNames(keyGenres, paste0(".*", tolower(keyGenres), ".*"))
result = str_replace_all(tolower(gens), pattern = pat_replace)
result
# [1] "Jazz"  "Rock"  "Rock"  "Rock"  "Blues" "Blues"
```

Using this data:

```
gens = c("Jazz Fusion", "Latin Rock, Progressive Rock", "Progressive Rock", 
"Blues Rock, Electric Blues", "Electric Texas Blues, Electric Blues", "Piano Blues, Chicago Blues")
keyGenres = c("Pop","Rock","Hip Hop","Latin","Dance","Electronic","R&B","Country","Folk","Acoustic","Classical","Metal","Jazz","New Age","Blues","World","Traditional")
```